# turn 3g on/off android 4.4 or above

Tags: android, eclipse, 3g

My SDK upgraded and I can not enable or disable 3G with code on Eclipse.

This code doesnt work anymore.

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws
        ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException,
        NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager
        .getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass
        .getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

Comment: Only system apps can do that now :(

Comment: Reflection == It can stop work at any moment

Answer (score 0):

Applications aren't supposed to turn 3g/4g/GPS on or off by themselves. There were glitches/workarounds that have allowed it but they aren't reliable, since they are getting fixed.

What you should do, is notify the user that their 3g state needs to change, maybe with an **AlertDialog**, and give them the option to navigate to the phone settings page, **via an intent**, where they can manually enable 3g.